# vscode can't debug mocha test with es6 babel

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, babeljs, mocha.js

Getting error `Cannot use import statement outside a module` when runing from vscode debug.

When I run mocha from command line it works perfectly fine.

VSCode config:

```
{
      "args": [
        "test",
        "--require @babel/register"
      ],
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "name": "Mocha Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha",
      "request": "launch",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "node"
    },
```

command line which isworking: `./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test --require @babel/register --exit`

Answer (score 0):

This configuration worked for me

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Mocha Tests",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha",
      "args": [
        "test",
        "--require",  "@babel/register",
        "--timeout", "999999",
        "--colors"
      ],
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"]
    }
```

Also updated all bable packages to 7.x earlier I had `babel-cli` in my dependencies changed it with `@babel/cli`